# ContainerResponseFilter runs twice, header not modified

Tags: java, filter, jersey, jetty, servlet-filters

A filter intercepts all requests and adds a custom header to the response.

When I implement ContainerResponseFilter, the filter method runs twice:

```
@Provider
public class MyCustomFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter throws IOException {

   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, 
    ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) {
       containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("My-Key", "myvalue");
    }

}
```

And, the response that is served to the client does *not* contain the header.

I've tried debugging both the Jetty and Jersey configuration, and have narrowed the problem down to the following legacy controller logic I can't modify:

```
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter printout = new PrintWriter(out);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(dummyData);
        printout.print(obj);
```

It seems that writing directly to the response stream triggers some JAX-RS lifecycle chain that leads to an extra processing phase.

I'm on Jersey 2.52.1 and Jetty 9.4.4.

Comment: I'm running with 2 connectors and virtualhosts on Jetty. I've tried running just one. Same thing. I'm running two different ResourceConfigs for Jersey, but only register the filter package for one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

It seems that accessing outputstream and doing printwriter.print() triggered the HttpServletResponse "WRITE" status and starts returning the response to the client.

So in my controller:

```
@GET
@Path("/seatemperatures")
public HttpServletResponse modifyResponse(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    UtilClass.workOnResponse(request, response); //this uses printwriter.write()
    return response;
}
```

I had to change the return type to void:

```
@GET
@Path("/seatemperatures")
public void modifyResponse(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    UtilClass.workOnResponse(request, response);
}
```

Returning the response object from the controller seems to cause an internal 500 error and effectively tried returning two response objects.